# A professor wanted me to wait for his decision. It's been about 10 days, what should I write to show that I want to know how long it is going to take?

Tags: graduate-admissions, professorship, email

I am a PhD applicant and a professor interviewed me for joining his team. I waited for his intention regarding my case, after two weeks he emailed me that I should "wait a little bit longer". It's been almost 10 days from his email and about a month after our last interview. How should I write an email to show both that I am still waiting for his response (and interested in his work),and I need to know a timeline for his decision?
*It is already late to get an admission!

Comment: Is this your only application to PhD program? Or you have other applications pending as well?

Comment: I have other pending applications as well

Comment: In fact, I have another application in the same situation(professor wants me to wait), and another pending (I am in waiting list). It seems that I am plan B every where!

Comment: "It seems that I am plan B every where!" That's only true if you've applied everywhere. Have you? How many applications did you send out yesterday? How many applications did you send out the week before? Come on, be honest. And if you believe the deadline for academic applications has already passed for the next academic period, you need to start working on your own plan B (just in case). May be apply for a job, or plan to travel abroad, or prepare your resume, or whatever. My point is that you must keep on moving forward.

Comment: So you are playing the same game as the professor - they want the best student; you want the best professor. That's life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like he's asking you to wait because you're his plan B, not his plan A. In other words, he may be afraid that his favorite candidate backs out, and he's keeping you in the wings just in case that happens.

So should you push the issue? No, not unless you have other offers. And if your other pending applications haven't been responded to yet, it's in your best interest to wait until those other decisions come back to you.

Comment: Sounds a good answer.